# PySpark Py4JJavaError when trying to write to csv file

Tags: pyspark

I am running a sample script to filter data from a csv file. I'm trying to save the filtered data into another csv file. But it gives an error.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("large_dataset_example").getOrCreate()

# Create a DataFrame from the CSV file
df = spark.read.csv("data.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)

# Show the first 5 rows of the DataFrame
df.show(5)

# Filter the DataFrame
filtered_df = df.filter((df.age >= 30) & (df.gender == "Male"))

# Show the filtered DataFrame
filtered_df.show()

# Group the DataFrame by gender and compute the average age
avg_age_df = filtered_df.groupBy("gender").agg({"age": "avg"})

# Show the average age DataFrame
avg_age_df.show()

#####################################################################

# Write the filtered and aggregated data to a new CSV file
filtered_df.write.csv("filtered_data.csv", header=True)
avg_age_df.write.csv("average_age.csv", header=True)
```

It is running all good untile `write.csv`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 2
      1 # Write the filtered and aggregated data to a new CSV file
----> 2 filtered_df.write.csv("filtered_data.csv", header=True)
      3 avg_age_df.write.csv("average_age.csv", header=True)

File C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:1240, in DataFrameWriter.csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue, lineSep)
   1221 self.mode(mode)
   1222 self._set_opts(
   1223     compression=compression,
   1224     sep=sep,
   (...)
   1238     lineSep=lineSep,
   1239 )
-> 1240 self._jwrite.csv(path)

File C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:851)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$26(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    ... 42 more
```

I'm running the script on Windows11 and the environment is setting as

```
setx JAVA_HOME “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202”
setx SPARK_HOME “C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3”
setx HADOOP_HOME “C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3”
setx PATH “%PATH%;C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\bin”
```

---

After putting the spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3 folder to `C:\Users\xxx`, which is suggested by @Lamanus, and set the environment variabls as

```
setx JAVA_HOME “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202”
setx SPARK_HOME “C:\Users\xxx\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3”
setx HADOOP_HOME “C:\Users\xxx\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3”
setx PATH “%PATH%;C:\Users\xxx\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\bin”
```

it still gives an error.

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 2
      1 # Write the filtered and aggregated data to a new CSV file
----> 2 filtered_df.write.csv("filtered_data.csv", header=True)
      3 avg_age_df.write.csv("average_age.csv", header=True)

File ~\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:1240, in DataFrameWriter.csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue, lineSep)
   1221 self.mode(mode)
   1222 self._set_opts(
   1223     compression=compression,
   1224     sep=sep,
   (...)
   1238     lineSep=lineSep,
   1239 )
-> 1240 self._jwrite.csv(path)

File ~\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
...
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    ... 42 more
```

The dataset is not large as described. It has only 10 rows.
id,name,age,gender

```
1,John,30,Male
2,Jane,25,Female
3,Mark,40,Male
4,Sara,35,Female
5,David,28,Male
6,Emily,32,Female
7,Steven,45,Male
8,Amy,27,Female
9,Chris,50,Male
10,Lisa,42,Female
```

Comment: Do you have installed hadoop or winutils?

Comment: @Lamanus I didn't install hadoop. I put winutils.exe in `C:\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3\bin`

Comment: Then please check the permission. All the paths are in C:\, so user might cannot read the files. I prefer to install the spark and winutils under the user home path.

Comment: @Lamanus I try to move the folder to `C:\Users\xxx\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop` and change the environment variable to `C:\Users\xxx\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3`. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you set the env variables through the os? https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows11

Answer (score 0):

After trying 2 days. GPT4 helps me solve the problem.

1. Open a new PowerShell session as an administrator
2. Run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in the administrator PowerShell session
3. conda init powershell
4. restart the PowerShell session as an administrator
5. `conda activate env-name`, `jupyter notebook`
6. Run the script and the problem is solved